# Rails 3.2.9 and models in subfolders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loading

Since rails 3.2.9 I'm unable to store models in subfolders. In my app I have this tree:

```
models
 -type_models
 -assets
 -user
 -concerns
```

Also in application.rb there is

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/models/*"]
```

All things was ok till rails 3.2.9. Now I have "Unknown constant" error.
I don't want to namespace tons of model and fix all app to use namespaced models.

```
Warning: Error loading /var/www/my_app/app/models/type_models/context_type.rb:
uninitialized constant TypeModels::ContextType
```

file context_type.rb:

```
class ContextType ... end
```

Comment: Why don't you want to namespace all your models? That is the convention.

Comment: Because it was ok in 3.2.8?

Comment: Did you find a solution also looking for this, with rails 4 that is

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/models/**/"]
```

Comment: Warning: Error loading /var/www/my_app/app/models/type_models/context_type.rb:
uninitialized constant TypeModels::ContextType

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18934115/rails-4-organize-rails-models-in-sub-path-without-namespacing-models

Did you restart your app after the change?

Answer (score 0):

in `config/application.rb`:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(type_models assets user concerns).map { |folder| "#{config.root}/app/models/#{folder}"}
```

in `models/type_models/context_type.rb`:

```
class TypeModels::ContextType < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end
```

Restart Rails and you're all set!

Answer (score -1):

Wrap your `class ContextType ... end` to module:

```
module TypeModels
  class ContextType
    # blah blah
  end
end
```