# Using Rails autoload_path, Unable to autoload constant expected incorrect subfolder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, monologue

I am using the [Monologue](https://github.com/jipiboily/monologue/) Gem and [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) Gem.

I am using config autoload_paths to load my subdirectories which include some presentation models.

[Rails 4: organize rails models in sub path without namespacing models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18934115/rails-4-organize-rails-models-in-sub-path-without-namespacing-models)

**app/config/application.rb**

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'models', '{*/}')]
```

My issue, I believe, stems from when I needed to override the Monologue User model.  To do so I created a local file

**app/models/monologue/user.rb**

```
class Monologue::User < ActiveRecord::Base
    # code
end
```

I also have my app's user model at

**app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    # code
end
```

The error that I am recieving is

> ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:481:in `load_missing_constant': Unable to autoload constant User, expected
>   /Users/Shared/code/kindrdfood/RecRm/app/models/monologue/user.rb to
>   define it (LoadError)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've included a part of the classes namespace into the autoload path (`app/models/monologue`).

Just keep the autoloading path as it is. The path `app/models` is already included. Rails tries to find an appropriate file to include for a given class name if it does not exist yet. Without your modification to the load path, `User` should autoload `app/models/user.rb` and `Monologue::User` should autoload `app/models/monologue/user.rb`.

What Rails actually does, is calling the `underscore` method on a your class (respectively its string representation). So on a Rails console, you could do something like this:

```
>> "Monologue::User".underscore
=> "monologue/user"

>> "User".underscore
=> "user"
```

Edit:

If you want to add custom load pathes to rails' autoload feature, I'd recommend to not put them inside of a folder which is already included in the list. Maybe something like this:

```
config.autoload_paths << File.join(config.root, "app/decorators")
config.autoload_paths << File.join(config.root, "app/workers")
config.autoload_paths << File.join(config.root, "lib")
```

Comment: TY for reply.  The auto load path is adjusted to include folders for presenter/decorator models as shown in this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/q/18934115/2842709