# Rails' autoloading/constant resolution is creating ghost modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here's [a brand new Rails 5.1.4 app](https://github.com/stulentsev/ghost_module), with a model and a couple of routes and controllers.

A namespaced controller is referencing a top level model:

```
class AdminArea::WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @user = User.new(name: 'Sergio')
  end
end
```

So far so good. You can check out the master, navigate to `http://localhost:3000/admin_area/welcome` and see it work.

BUT if we [were to add an empty directory `app/presenters/admin_area/user/` *](https://github.com/stulentsev/ghost_module/pull/1), then things get weird. All of a sudden, `User` in that controller is not my model, but a non-existing module!

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `new' for AdminArea::User:Module):

app/controllers/admin_area/welcome_controller.rb:3:in `index'
```

Naturally, this module doesn't have any [non-built-in] methods and can't be pinned to a source file on disk.

**Question**: why adding an empty directory causes rails to mysteriously conjure a module out of thin air instead of correctly resolving name `User` to my model?

---

<sup>* actually, if you check out that branch as-is, you'll get a different error.</sup>

> <sup>NameError (uninitialized constant AdminArea::WelcomeController::User)</sup>

<sup>because git wouldn't let me commit an empty directory, so I added a `.keep` file in there. But as soon as you delete that file, you get the behaviour described above.</sup>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails 4: organize rails models in sub path without namespacing models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18934115/rails-4-organize-rails-models-in-sub-path-without-namespacing-models)

Comment: @jon1467: no, not a duplicate of that. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Ah sorry, I think I misread your question as asking how to place your user model in the directory `presenters`. My bad.

Comment: I think [this issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3841#issuecomment-3002705) could describe your problem, no indication if this was ever fixed/changed.

Comment: @jon1467: closer, but still no. `Module.nesting` does not affect things here. In the sample app it is `AdminArea::WelcomeController`, but in my actual app, it's a proper nesting (`module AdminArea; class WelcomeController`). Both exhibit the same behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This a consequence of ruby constant lookup and how Rails resolves autoloading.

The constant `User` in the controller is so called ["relative reference"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoloading-algorithms-relative-references), which means it should be resolved relative to the namespace within which it occurs. 
For this constant, there are three possible variants where the constant can be defined:

```
AdminArea::WelcomeController::User
AdminArea::User
User
```

Rails autoloading maps these constants into file names and iterates over the [`autoload_path`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoload-paths)s in order to find the file where the constant is defined. E.g.:

```
app/assets/admin_area/welcome_controller/user.rb
app/assets/admin_area/welcome_controller/user
app/channels/admin_area/welcome_controller/user.rb
...
app/assets/admin_area/user.rb
app/assets/admin_area/user
...
app/assets/user.rb
...
app/models/user.rb #=> here it is!
```

When you add the `admin_area/user` folder into the presenters directory, you are effectively defining such a constant. [Modules in Rails are automagically created](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#automatic-modules), so that you don't actually need to create files where you define these modules that only work as namespaces.

When you added the folder, the folder appeared in the Rails lookup:

```
...
app/assets/admin_area/user.rb
app/assets/admin_area/user
...
app/presenters/admin_area/user #=> Here Rails finds the folder
```

and Rails resolves the `User` to reference to that module.

However this is quite easy to fix, If you want the `User` constant that is used within `AdminArea` namespace to reference a top-level constant (and not the `AdminArea::User` module), you should change the "relative reference" into an **absolute reference** by preceding the constant with `::`.

```
@user = ::User.new(name: 'Sergio')
```

Comment: The only missing piece, I think, is link to the code that automagically creates modules.

Comment: There you go http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#automatic-modules :)
"If autoload_paths has a file called admin.rb Rails is going to load that one, but if there's no such file and a directory called admin is found, Rails creates an empty module and assigns it to the Admin constant on the fly."

Comment: That's it, thanks! I'll award the bounty as soon as it lets me :)