# Unable to autoload constant API Controller in Rails 4 model in module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create an api controller for a model defined in a module

Model class:

```
module Reports
  class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  end
end
```

Api controller:

```
class API::V2::ReportsController < API::V2::BaseController

end
```

Route:

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
  namespace :v2 do
    resources :reports
  end
end
```

The error I get when try to call api/v2/reports is:

```
LoadError (Unable to autoload constant Report, expected /.../app/models/reports/report.rb to define it):
```

Is there a way to solve this, making the api controller look for Reports::Report instead of Report?

Comment: There is no way to achieve this. You need write Reports::Report all the time. But I wonder why you need namespaced model?

Comment: @andriy-baran I have to isolate the model for colliding names. So you are saying all models should be defined as root??

Comment: Please read this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18934115/rails-4-organize-rails-models-in-sub-path-without-namespacing-models

Answer (score 0):

Your controller needs to include `Reports` somehow:

```
module Api
  module V2
    module Reports
      class Report < API::V2::BaseController

        your controller actions

      end
    end
  end
end
```

Apart from that, I think it will be confusing if you use `Reports::Report`?

Comment: I tried also this, but with no luck. It gives me the same error

Comment: what's the path file for your Reports:Report?
should be `./app/models/reports/report.rb` as the error you get suggests

Comment: the path is that

Comment: I just realised your routes are missing one nested namespace for `reports` as well, but the whole naming looks weird to me and not sure if rails will be getting confused. The module's name  should be singular and then you might have a Finance report or something, `Reports::Report` is confusing in my opinion

Comment: I also tried with a different naming, changing Reports::Report with Reporting::Report and consequently all the classes and controller. I also tried to add the Reporting namespace but the error is always the same